# C++ Compile time consistent identifier generation

Tags: c++

I need to implement a type index structure that would correctly and consistently identify every type in the project.

The issue with using something like `std::type_index` is that it needs to be consistent across different compilation units.
I need it to be consistent between compilation units as I would be loading shared libraries as sub modules at runtime (thus they would not be linked to the main module) and they should all have the same indexes for the same types, and if I use `std::type_index` or a custom index generating function each compilation unit would have it's own implementation of index generation and thus the index can be inconsistent.

Is there any template way to generate unique indexes for types that is consistent across compilation units (ex. `TypeA` would have index `1` on first compile and the 2nd)?

Is there maybe any tool that would allow me to feed the source code into and consistently generate hard-coded indexes from that?

Comment: What is the actual use case?  You should not be relying on the C++ type system for this kind of behavior, since `typeinfo` and `typeindex` are designed around the context of distinguishing types at runtime.  What is stopping you from registering your types with your own custom solution?  You could do this as a pre-build step that generates code based on some configuration file, for example.

Comment: Maybe you can use Boost.Hana::type, https://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1type.html . I have no idea how it works and if it is consistent as you demand.

Comment: `std::type_index` is exactly as consistent as `std::type_info`. Why do you think there is an issue with consistency?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. The module binary would be compiled independently from the host binary, so each would have it's own `std::type_index`s generated and the equality of those is implementation defined behavior afaik.

Comment: @paddy That is what i am asking about mainly. The question is if there is any tool or template based solution for, as you said, registering the types and generating preset indexes (be it a 0 based index, hash or uuid)

Comment: type_index just a wrapper around a pointer to type_info. Do you think two different types can have the same type_info object?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Two different types would never have the same type_info, i did not mean that. What can cause an issue is that library `module1.so` can have it's own `type_info` for `SomeType` while `module2.so` could have a different `type_info` for `SomeType` as the libraries are compiled independently. This means that you would not be able to use the `type_index` across binary boundary

Comment: The standard doesn't promise that you have an ability to use shared libraries at all, however you seem to be fine with using them without any guarantees from the standard. Why do you believe that the same type has the same layout in two different libraries? You cannot even ask this question in a portable manner. You need to rely on the implementation documenting this somehow, or else just try it and see if it works. It is normal for an implementation to produce the same layout, any non-evil one does that. It is also normal to merge all type_info objects across shared libraries (weak symbols).

Comment: An implementation that doesn't do that would not be able to throw exceptions across shared libraries, for example, unless it has a completely separate and private type_info replacement that it doesn't expose to the programmer out of sheer spite. All the normal implementations just use type_info to identify exceptions. Even if an implementation is unable to physically merge the symbols, it has to make comparison between type_info and type_index work, so they are logically indistinguishable.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. The issue comes exactly from the fact that the standard doesn't guarantee anything about shared libraries. Because the way type_info is generated is implementation defined you cannot rely on the fact that two shared_infos would be identical across libraries. This is what my question is about, i need some way to identify types that is not implementation defined so it would be consistent across libraries.

Comment: I cannot rely on weak symbols to merge type_infos because the libraries are loaded as modules at runtime (ex. dlopen) thus there would be no way for the linker to resolve the type_info symbols

Comment: You can rely on literally nothing when shared libraries are involved. Everything and anything there is implementation defined. Why do you focus on type_info specifically? Implementations do try hard to make `type_info` and `type_index` for the same type compare equal across DLL, their efforts are documented. So you can choose to trust your implementation to do the right thing, and perhaps report a bug if it doesn't; or you can choose to eliminate all behaviour that is not explicitly allowed in the standard, and end up never releasing any useful software.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It is true that using a non standard functionality would be sometimes better than not doing anything. You say that implementations try to make type_index compare equal cross libraries, could you please link some articles/documentation about that? Would be interesting to read on that myself.

Comment: I stand corrected.  At least some versions of libc++ don't do that, there is an open bug about it https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37398. Comparing type info across shared libraries doesn't work correctly for this implementation. There are some open-source projects that switched from comparing type_info or type_index to comparing type_info::name because of this issue. This is not guaranteed by the standard to produce unique or consistent results, however all implementations that I know of do that as one would expect.

Comment: And, predictably enough, throwing an exception across shared library boundaries doesn't work in this implementation either. What a shame.